# TFS 2010 - List Shelvesets for Gated Checkin

Tags: tfsbuild

Is there a way to get list of Shelvesets ( not shelveset details ) done using a Gated Checkin from commandline

will tf.exe history command list out shelvsets ??

NOTE : There is one shelveset command , but this command expects shelveset name to list its details,my requirement is to get the list of shelvesets

Thanks,

Sunil.V

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on exactly what you want to accomplish, but tf shelvesets may do the trick.  For example, try the following command:

tf shelvesets /owner * | findstr Gated_

This will list gated check-in shelvesets.

Ed

Comment: Hi Ed Hintz,  


Thanks for your reply,my requirement is to get the shelveset name and details which caused a build failure due to incorrect checkins ( Gated Checkin ).


command which you mentioned tf shelvesets /owner * | findstr Gated_ works well only when i know who the owner is ( anybody from team can checkin the code )


im looking for something like , 

pusedo code : tf.exe shelvesets previoubuild~currentbuild

Hope im clear